# create 2d depth image from sparse 360 degree pointcloud

Tags: pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any ROS/PCL package available already to achieve this?
Thanks for the help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277191/create-2d-depth-image-from-sparse-360-degree-pointcloud/) by [tbb](https://answers.ros.org/users/32684/tbb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-12-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@Jeremie thanks for the package again. I was able to create a 360 degree range image from my Lidar point cloud. Although you also said that some further work would be needed as well? Could you elaborate which features you think are missing for using the PCL method creating range images? I've wanted to attach a sample image, but got too few points on this board yet unfortunately.

---

Originally posted by [tbb](https://answers.ros.org/users/32684/tbb/) with karma: 16 on 2017-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Petros ADLATUS](https://answers.ros.org/users/99003/petros-adlatus/) on 2022-03-31**:
can you share this package?